# Calculate dynamically width of elements

Tags: html, css, angular, kendo-ui, alignment

I have array of elements that I want to display, and I want to create this all tiles in same width, and make div 100% width. (In this code the tile sizes are different). Any help is much appreciated.

[image: now it's shown like this]

```
<div class="summaryArea" align="center">
    <div *ngFor="let item of getSummery()">
      <kendo-tilelayout [rowHeight]="200" [resizable]="true">
        <kendo-tilelayout-item>
          <kendo-tilelayout-item-body align="center">
            <div class="summary" align="center">
              <h4>{{item.amount}}</h4>
              <div *ngIf="item.status == 'up'"><span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-60-up k-icon-md" style="color:green"></span></div>
              <div *ngIf="item.status == 'down'"><span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-60-down k-icon-md" style="color:red"></span></div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div>{{item.name}}</div>
            <hr />
            <div>{{item.Description}} </div>
          </kendo-tilelayout-item-body>
        </kendo-tilelayout-item>
      </kendo-tilelayout>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is my CSS

```
.summary {
  display:inline-flex;
}    
.summaryArea {
  width:fit-content;
  font-size:medium;
  display: flex;
}
```

I tried like this but this not works

```
<kendo-tilelayout-item [width] ="calculatewidth(getSummery().length)">
```

Ts file

```
  public calculatewidth(length) {
    return 100 / length+'%';
  }
```

Comment: please refer this https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/tilelayout/reordering
There is one field name as `columnsWidth` for define width of the coloumn. `Ex: columnsWidth: "100%",`

Comment: @Pra To equally give each tile item the same width, you just need to do `kendo-tilelayout [columns]="4"`. Where `4` is the number of tile items you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using following code. Thanks All for your effort

```
<div class="summaryArea">
          <div *ngFor="let item of getSummery()" [style.width]="calculatewidth(getSummery().length)">
            <kendo-tilelayout [rowHeight]="170">
              <kendo-tilelayout-item>
                <kendo-tilelayout-item-body align="center">

                  //content

                </kendo-tilelayout-item-body>
              </kendo-tilelayout-item>
            </kendo-tilelayout>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Css

```
.summaryArea {
  width:100%;
  font-size:medium;
  display: flex;
}
```

ts

```
  public calculatewidth(length) {
    return 100 / length + '%';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

what if the `width` in the `.summaryArea` area is changed to `width : 100%`? is the result what you want?

Comment: width:100% did not work. I want to fill the div 100% using same size tiles.

Answer (score -1):

try by using 25% each because it is 4 box

Comment: It generate dynamically. the array has only 4 items. That's why it shows 4. If array has 5 elements, tile width must change